# $x\sim y$ if $|x-y|\le 3$, then is $\sim $ or R an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let R or $\sim$ be the relation defined on Z by
$$x\sim y\text{ if } |x-y| \le 3$$
Is $\sim$ an equivalence relation?

It is reflexive and symmetric if I did it correctly. However, I am having doubt about transitive.

Transitive:

Assume $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, then, $$|a-b|\le 3\text{ and }|b-c|\le 3$$
$$|a-c|\le |a-b|+|b-c|\le 3+3 =6$$

This is where I am stuck at. I am not sure if I should conclude $|a-c|\le 6$ and it is not transitive.

Comment: Deducing $|a-c|\leq 6$ doesn't let you _conclude_ that it is not transitive, but the fact that you didn't get anything better might _suggest_ that it isn't. How about you look for a counterexample?

Comment: My house and Wojowu's are 3 blocks away from yours. Does that mean that I live 3 blocks away from Wojowu?

Comment: $1 \sim 4$ and $4 \sim 7$ but clearly $1 \not\sim 7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x=-3,y=0,z=3$. Then, $x \sim y$ since their difference is exactly 3, and $y \sim z$ for the same reason. But $x \not\sim z$ since their difference is exactly 6.

Answer (score 0):

Think about pairs $0,3$ and $3,6$ -- is $(0,6) \in R$?

Answer (score 0):

We have $6\sim3$ and $3\sim0$, but is $6\sim0$ true?